# Rails find id on the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

On controller usually use params to get id and on the model? i've trying to get using the exemple below:

in either case did not get id, so how to get the id or any attributes on the model?

```
def nook
   product = Product.find_by_id(:id)
   nook.product_id
end
def product
    prod = Product.find_by_id(attributes['product_id']) 
end
```

Comment: Can you explain the question properly? It's not clear.

Comment: @Saran thank you i edited

Comment: Params are not available to models.

Comment: you want to access the params in model @japalow?

Comment: @Saran  yes please

Comment: It's not a good practice to use params in the model. If you really want to use the params in a model (which you shouldn't) you can define a class method in the model and call the method in your controller and pass the params.(This is a bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

In your controller use params hash

```
   product = Product.find_by_id(params[:id])
```